# This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am getting the error when my Azure Web app tries to access the SQL Azure Database. Does anybody know why that would happen?

This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Comment: There is an SQL Azure outage right now, see: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: There is currently a DNS issue in Azure - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/.

Comment: Yes they've updated the status now. I checked it before posting here. It was just the SQL Azure Database that was not accessible. But now none of the services are working. Hopefully they sort that out soon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a service outage transient error. Not a programming question.

Comment: @PrithviRamana - please delete this question. Several other extraneous questions have also popped up and unfortunately they aren't helpful - they are strictly related to today's DNS outage and will ultimately be useless in the future. And also, there's nothing that can be resolved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: With the Azure services getting disrupted a couple of times in the past week, and we not having a support plan in place and the Azire service status page not showing the immediate status, we will have to rely on stackoverflow and twitter @AzureSupport for questions like this. Just wanted to know what this error meant in Azure and came to know about the service status after.

I will delete this post at the end of play today.